# angular2: building svg icons with *ngIf adds nothing to DOM

Tags: javascript, svg, angular, angular-ng-if

I am using icoMoon to import some SVG icons.

The html I want to build using ngIf follows this pattern:

```
<div class="contactIcon">
    <svg class="icon icon-envelop">
        <use xlink:href="symbol-defs.svg#icon-envelop"></use>
    </svg>
</div>
```

So I'm exporting the icons array with icon and xlink properties:

```
export class NavigationComponent {
    icons = [{
            icon: 'icon icon-envelop',
            xlink: 'symbol-defs.svg#icon-envelop'
        },
        {
            icon: 'icon icon-facebook2',
            xlink: 'symbol-defs.svg#icon-facebook2'
        },
        {
            icon: 'icon icon-linkedin',
            xlink: 'symbol-defs.svg#icon-linkedin'
        },
        {
            icon: 'icon icon-mobile',
            xlink: 'symbol-defs.svg#icon-mobile'
        }];
}
```

and my html looks like this:

```
<div *ngFor="#i of icons" class="contactIcon">
    <svg [attr.class]="i.icon">
        <use [attr.xlink:href]="i.xlink"></use>
    </svg>
</div>
```

But when I inspect the page, nothing gets added, and no errors are shown in the console. All I see is this comment:

```
<!--template bindings={}-->
```

Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I remember the workaround is to add the `xlink:href` attribute statically. Binding can modify such SVG attributes, only adding doesn't work. This is some underlying browser issue. Polymer suffers the same:

```
<div *ngFor="#i of icons" class="contactIcon">
    <svg [attr.class]="i.icon">
        <use xlink:href="" [attr.xlink:href]="i.xlink"></use>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I found the corresponding question and tried it this way, but it's still the same, only see the template bindings comment

Comment: Ok, I'll try it in a Plunker

Comment: no need. I was updating the wrong component. Your solution works as expected, thanks a lot.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have a similar problem: `<svg width="220" height="116"  *ngIf="show" ...` throws an error: Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of ':svg:svg'. ngIf works any other part of the application except on SVG!

Comment: Are you sure the module that contains the SVG has the `CommonModule` imported?